# Terraform Shared VPC on GCP - Static Internal IP address

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am attempting to write automation to deploy instances in a shared VPC on GCP. I have a host network project and a service project. I can create a static internal IP address resource in the host project (resource "google_compute_address" "internal") in which I specify the VPC host project (NET_HUB_PROJ) but I am unable to use it when creating the instance. I receive the following error:

```
google_compute_instance.compute: Error creating instance: googleapi: 
Error 400: Invalid value for field 
'resource.networkInterfaces[0].networkIP': '10.128.0.10'. IP address 
'projects/prototype-network-hub/regions/us-central1/addresses/bh-int- 
ip' (10.128.0.10) is reserved by another project., invalid
```

My compute module:

```
data "google_compute_image" "image" {
  name    = "${var.IMAGE_NAME}"
  project = "${var.IMAGE_PROJECT}"
}

resource "google_compute_address" "internal" {
  name         = "${var.NAME}-int-ip"
  address_type = "INTERNAL"
  address      = "${var.PRIVATE_IP}"
  subnetwork   = "${var.NET_HUB_SUBNETWORK}"
  region       = "${var.NET_HUB_REGION}"
  project      = "${var.NET_HUB_PROJ}"
}

resource "google_compute_address" "external" {
  count        = "${var.EXT_IP_CREATE ? 1 : 0}"
  name         = "${var.NAME}-ext-ip"
  address_type = "EXTERNAL"
  region       = "${var.REGION}"
}

resource "google_compute_instance" "compute" {
   depends_on  = ["google_compute_address.external"] 
   name = "${var.NAME}"
   machine_type = "${var.MACHINE_TYPE}"
   zone = "${var.ZONE}"
   can_ip_forward = "${var.CAN_IP_FORWARD}"
   deletion_protection ="${var.DELETION_PROTECTION}"
   allow_stopping_for_update = "${var.ALLOW_STOPPING_FOR_UPDATE}"
   tags = ["allow-ssh"]
   metadata = {
    "network" = "${var.NETWORK}"
    "env" = "${var.ENV}"
    "role" = "${var.ROLE}"
    "region" = "${var.REGION}"
    "zone" = "${var.ZONE}"
   }
   labels = {
    "network" = "${var.NETWORK}"
    "env" = "${var.ENV}"
    "role" = "${var.ROLE}"
    "region" = "${var.REGION}"
    "zone" = "${var.ZONE}"
    }
   boot_disk {
      device_name = "${var.NAME}"
      auto_delete = "${var.BOOT_DISK_AUTO_DELETE}"
      initialize_params {
      size = "${var.BOOT_DISK_SIZE}"
      type = "${var.BOOT_DISK_TYPE}"
      image = "${data.google_compute_image.image.self_link}"
      }
   }

network_interface {
   network_ip = "${google_compute_address.internal.address}"
   subnetwork_project = "${var.NET_HUB_PROJ}"
   subnetwork   = "projects/prototype-network-hub/regions/us-central1/subnetworks/custom"
   access_config {
      nat_ip = "${element(concat(google_compute_address.external.*.address, list("")), 0)}"
   }
}
service_account {
   scopes = ["service-control", "service-management", "logging-write", "monitoring-write", "storage-ro", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append" ]
   }
}
```

The end goal would be to accomplish the following:
[image]

Comment: Have you checked that `10.128.0.10` was not used by another resource?

Comment: It is not being used by any other resource. I can confirm it has been created in the host networking project (prototype-network-hub) but not applied to any resource. The error msg alludes to that. It just specifies that it is reserved by the project. One interesting thing to note is using TF, I see an internal IP reservation: https://www.evernote.com/l/AfdR3FOkeFZPubjfrEWmcVA1II2uk8cU3qE, but when manually reserved as seen in the picture in my above post, it does not.

Answer (score 5):

EDIT **(new answer)**:
Per the GCP documentation, the static internal IP must belong to the service project (not the host network project as in your code) if you're looking to reserve internal IP on a shared VPC in a different project. See here: 
https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/provisioning-shared-vpc#reserve_internal_ip

Seeing as a `shared-vpc` is unlikely to be found in your TF codebase, you'll have to use `data` to get the `self_link` of the subnetwork to use for `google_compute_address`. Something like the following:

```
data "google_compute_subnetwork" "subnet" {
  name    = "${var.NET_HUB_SUBNETWORK}"
  project = "${var.NET_HUB_PROJ}"
  region  = "${var.NET_HUB_REGION}"
}

resource "google_compute_address" "internal" {
  name         = "${var.NAME}-int-ip"
  address_type = "INTERNAL"
  address      = "${var.PRIVATE_IP}"
  subnetwork   = "${data.google_compute_subnetwork.subnet.self_link}"
}
```

This should create the resource under your service project, yet with an address within the designated subnet.

When you deploy your instance you should see it referenced under the `internal_ip` column on your VM instances tab for the assigned instance.

**(old answer for posterity)**:
Unfortunately, `google_compute_address` doesn't contain a `subnetwork_project` like `google_compute_instance`. A fix around this is to provide a full URL to the `subnetwork` field in `google_compute_address`. Something like the following:

```
resource "google_compute_address" "internal" {
  name         = "${var.NAME}-int-ip"
  address_type = "INTERNAL"
  address      = "${var.PRIVATE_IP}"
  subnetwork   = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/${var.NET_HUB_PROJ}/regions/${var.NET_HUB_REGION}/subnetworks/${var.NET_HUB_SUBNETWORK}"
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem but it doesn't work.

Comment: I finally figure it out.  When creating the compute_address, I have to use my service project, not my host project.  Once I use my service project, everything just works.  Sorry for any confusion.  solution provided below

Answer (score 1):

Adding my solution below:-

```
resource "google_compute_address" "internal_ip" {
  count        = 1
  name         = "${local.cluster_name}-int-ip-${count.index}"
  project      = <service project id>
  subnetwork   = <host project subnet self_link>
  address_type = "INTERNAL"
  region       = "asia-northeast1"
  purpose      = "GCE_ENDPOINT"
}

output "internal_ipaddr_info" {
  value = google_compute_address.internal_ip
}


resource "google_compute_instance" "test" {
  project        = module.gcp_service_project.project_id
  name           = "eps-gce-vm-d-swmgr-ane1-test"
  machine_type   = "n1-standard-1"
  zone           = "asia-northeast1-a"
  can_ip_forward = true
  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "centos7"
    }
  }

  network_interface {
    subnetwork = <host project subnet self_link>
    network_ip = google_compute_address.internal_ip[0].self_link

  }

}
```

Comment: hyy @jlim i am facing same issue since yesterday please help me out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68541347/how-to-attach-static-internal-ip-to-compute-instance-using-terraform?noredirect=1#comment121134535_68541347